# Restrict particular domain in email regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have an existing regex which validates the email input field.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9!$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*(\\.)?@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9ÄÖÜäöü](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-_ÄÖÜäöü]*[a-zA-Z0-9_ÄÖÜäöü])?\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}
```

Now, I want this regex to not match for two particular type of email IDs. Which are **wt.com** and **des.net**

To do that I made the following changes in the above expression like this.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9!$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*(\\.)?@(?!wt\\.com)(?!des\\.net)(?:[a-zA-Z0-9ÄÖÜäöü](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-_ÄÖÜäöü]*[a-zA-Z0-9_ÄÖÜäöü])?\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}
```

After this it does not matches with any email id which ends with the wt.com and des.net which is right.
But the problem is it does not match with wt.comm or any other letter after the restricted string too.. 
I just want to restrict email which ends with  **wt.com** and **des.net**
How do I do that? 
Below is the sample emails which should match or not.

1. ajcom@wt.com : no match
2. ajcom@aa.an : match
3. ajcom@wt.coms :match
4. ajcom@des.net : no match
5. ajcom@des.neta: match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent only `wt.com` and `des.net` which have no characters after it you can add `$` [anchor](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) (which represents end of string) at the end of each negative-look-ahead.

So instead of `(?!wt\\.com)(?!des\\.net)` use `(?!wt\\.com$)(?!des\\.net$)`